# Rate of convergence of an inductively defined sequence $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $x_0\in(0,1)$, $\mu>1$ and $f(x)=x-x^\mu$. Define $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. I need help proving that there exist positive $c_1, c_2$ such that
\begin{equation}
x_n\leq c_1 n^{-c_2}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Sorry... do you need help, or just something (anything) to copy/paste/turn in? "Help" would imply some own effort, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to prove that $x_n \in (0,1)$. Besides, the sequence $x_n$ is decreasing, hence this sequence converges to the solution of $x = x-x^\mu$ (which is $0$). In other word, $$x_n \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow +\infty} 0 \tag{1}$$

Now, we study the sequence $x_n^{1-\mu}$, we have
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}^{1-\mu} &= (x_n-x_n^{\mu})^{1-\mu} \\
&= x_n^{1-\mu}(1-x_n^{\mu-1})^{1-\mu} \\
&= x_n^{1-\mu}\left(1+(1-\mu) x_n^{\mu-1}-\frac{(1-\mu)\mu}{2} x_n^{2(\mu-1)}+ \mathcal{O}(x_n^{3(\mu-1)})   \right) \\
&= x_n^{1-\mu}+(1-\mu) -\frac{(1-\mu)\mu}{2} x_n^{(\mu-1)}+ \mathcal{O}(x_n^{2(\mu-1)}) \tag{2}   \\
\end{align}

From (1), we deduce that the terms $-\frac{(1-\mu)\mu}{2} x_n^{(\mu-1)}+ \mathcal{O}(x_n^{2(\mu-1)}) \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow +\infty} 0$, so from (2), we have
$$x_{n+1}^{1-\mu}-x_n^{1-\mu} \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow +\infty}(1-\mu) \tag{3}$$

According to the [Stolz-Cesano theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem_for_the_%E2%88%99/%E2%88%9E_case) for the case $a_n = x_n^{1-\mu}$ and $b_n=n$, we can deduce from (3) that
$$\frac{x_n^{1-\mu}}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow +\infty} (1-\mu)\iff \frac{x_n}{n^{-\frac{1}{\mu-1}}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow +\infty} (1-\mu)^{-\frac{1}{\mu-1}} \tag{4}$$

From (4), from the definition of limit, for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N_0(\epsilon)$ such that for all $n>N_0(\epsilon)$, we have
$$\left|\frac{x_n}{n^{-\frac{1}{\mu-1}}} - (1-\mu)^{-\frac{1}{\mu-1}} \right| \le \epsilon$$
In particular, for all $n>N_0(\epsilon)$, we have
$$x_n \le ((1-\mu)^{-\frac{1}{\mu-1}}+\epsilon)n^{-\frac{1}{\mu-1}}$$

Hence, we can define

$$c_2=\frac{1}{\mu-1}$$
$$c_1 = \max\left(1-\mu)^{-\frac{1}{\mu-1}}+\epsilon;  \max_{i=1,\ldots,N_0(\epsilon)}\left(\frac{x_i}{i^{-c_2}}\right) \right)$$

and then we can conclude that for all $n \ge 1$
$$x_n \le c_1 n^{-c_2}$$